# Grand canonical partition function as two factored canonical partition functions

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

The grand canonical ensemble can be written as a factored sum over two canonical partition functions, i.e.

$ Q^{tot} = \sum_{n=0}^{N^{tot}} Q^{a}(N^{tot}-n)\, Q^{b}(n) $,

where $Q^{a}$ is the reservoir (outer system) with $N^{tot}-n$ particles, and $Q^{b}$ is the inner system containing $n$ particles.

Let's say that $N^{tot} = 1$, then the partition function above could be written as two terms,

$ Q^{tot} = Q^a(1)\,Q^b(0) + Q^a(0)\,Q^b(1) $.

It looks like $Q^{tot}$ would always be zero in this case, as the canonical partition function when there are no states would always be zero. Where have I gone wrong, as this is clearly not true.

PS: I've worked with a factored partition function here because it's easier to show the problem. The same issue does occur in the purely grand canonical partition function but there's more working to see it. In any case the grand canonical partition function is typically derived from the expression for $Q^{tot}$ above.

#### Edit: more info on the application

I've got an iron substrate with a single-Fe vacancy in the centre of the cell. System $a$ represents the "bulk" part of the substrate and system $b$ is the vacancy. I have a single hydrogen atom in this cell, which can either be in the interstitial sites in the lattice (i.e. out of the vacancy) with energy -15.5 eV or in one of six sites in the vacancy with energy -16.1 eV. I'm basically trying to compute the expected number of hydrogen atoms in the vacancy $\langle n \rangle$ vs. temperature.

For the sake of numerical simplicity I take the interstitial energy to be my zero, so the energy of a hydrogen in system $a$ is zero and therefore the energy of a hydrogen in system $b$ is -0.6 eV.

Comment: A system with no particles in it has 1 state; it sits there empty.

Comment: What would the energy of this empty state be? i.e. $\sum_i g(E_i) exp[-\beta\,E_i] = g(E_0) exp[-\beta\,E_0] = exp[-\beta\,E_0] $.

Comment: You can always add a constant to the total energy and it has not observable consequences, so it does not really matter. All that matters is how then energy changes with the state of the system (e.g. you add some particles). Most of the time you would take $E_0 = 0$ unless there was some other convenient choice for your setup.

Comment: Ok but I'm using $E=0$ for a single particle in the bottom of the potential well, so I can't use $E=0$ for having no particles at all. The choice of $E$ for no particles does matter when I try to compute $\langle n^b \rangle$ (the expected number of particles in system $b$).

Comment: In that case you need to provide more information about your 2 systems. In order to factor the partition function you must be able to write the total energy of the combined system as $E_\mathrm{tot} = E_a + E_b$. How you arrive at this decomposition should tell you if there is an inherent energy cost (i.e. a chemical potential) to having particles in system $a$ rather than system $b$.

Comment: @BySymmetry okay thanks, I've just edited the original question to add more info on the problem I'm actually trying to solve.